# SSRS Single Row of Totals on New Page not Getting Headers on Page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have an SSRS layout as in the image below:

[image: Report Layout]

The report shows all data on one page, except for the very last row.  That row is not part of any group, so it's being placed on the second page all by itself.  The biggest problem with this is that the Header Row (Program Name, Section, etc.) doesn't show on the second page.

I have values set so the Header sticks to the top of the report window so that it stays visible when someone scrolls down the window.  In researching the problem, I seem to read that a single row not in a group doesn't capture the header when it is all by itself on a new page.  Am I understanding the problem correctly, and if so, is there any work around?

The second page looks like the below, and definitely needs headers for the values.

[image: Footer on Second Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that your line isn't part of a group and, without being forced to not, can be orphaned on it's own.

You should be able to force it together using the **KeepTogether** and **KeepWithGroup** properties. Make sure your grouping doesn't have a page break after that might be causing the issue.

[image: Grouping]

Comment: Those were already set.  What I did to solve the problem was to go back into the dataset and add a dummy variable, 0 AS Total, to the last section.  Then I added a group to the table, footer only, and grouped on 'Total', which always has the same value so will be a group of the whole dataset.  Then I set the Keep Together and KeepWithGroup property on the new group footer. Sorry, can't add a picture to a comment.  That fixed the problem.  The best I can figure is that a lone, ungrouped row will not pull over a header to another page, or stay with it's main display by setting Tablix properties.

Comment: Glad you got it working. I'll keep this in mind next time I have similar paging issues.